# Listing public folders

Tags: java, outlook, office365, exchangewebservices

I'm writing a program for importing contacts from an ERP system to Outlook. Different emails will receive different lists of contacts from ERP. The idea here is, in each email I have a public contact folder that can be accessed by a technical user. The technical user can write contacts into this folder. Here is the code for searching the folder:

```
protected FolderId findFolderId(String folderDisplayName, String userEmail) throws Exception {
    Mailbox userMailbox = new Mailbox(userEmail);
    FolderId contactRootFolder = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Root, userMailbox);

    FolderId result = null;
    FolderView view = new FolderView(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    view.setPropertySet(new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, FolderSchema.DisplayName));
    view.setTraversal(FolderTraversal.Deep);
    FindFoldersResults findFolderResults = this.service.findFolders(contactRootFolder, view);
    //find specific folder
    for (Folder f : findFolderResults) {
        if (folderDisplayName.equals(f.getDisplayName())) {
            result = f.getId();
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

The service object is created as follows:

```
this.service = new ExchangeService();
    ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials(userName, passWord);
    this.service.setCredentials(credentials);

    try {
        this.service.setUrl(new URI(URL));
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e);
    }
```

Where URL is the end point for the Exchange server (for Office 365 it is https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx).

The code works with Office 2010, I get the Id from that folder, connect to it and save the contacts. After the migration to Office 365, we can't find the public folder. It can just find a folder with the name "PeoplePublicData". (I don't even know that folder exists.)

Answer (score 1):

Throttling in Office365 means your code will only return the first 1000 folder in the Mailbox so if what your looking for isn't within that result set that would be one reason. I would suggest you get rid of

FolderView view = new FolderView(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

and change it to

FolderView view = new FolderView(1000);

and then page the results https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn592093(v=exchg.150).aspx which will allow you to get all the Folder in a Mailbox. Also unless you are looking for something in the Non_IPM_Subtree of the Mailbox start the search with MsgFolderRoot eg

FolderId contactRootFolder = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.MsgFolderRoot, userMailbox);

That will reduce the number of folders returned.

Also why don't you use a SearchFilter to search for the folder you are after eg https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633627(v=exchg.80).aspx this would eliminate the need to page the results,

Comment: Hi Glen,
thanks for the advice with SearchFilter. I will change the code.
After changing to WellKnowFolderName.MsgFolderRoot I got the Exeption  at the line where service.findFolders(...) occurs:
    Exception in thread "main" microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.exception.service.remote.ServiceResponseException: The specified object was not found in the store., The process failed to get the correct properties.

Comment: It sounds like you don't have access to the Mailbox eg you may have access to that specific folder your after but you will only be able to access it if you know the ewsId of the folder. You won't be able to search for that folder unless you have Full Access to the rest of the Mailbox

Comment: We have found the solution. In Office 365, the contact folder must be set as visible for the technical user. So does that means office 365 is more restrict than office 2013 ?